# STL Map<string, > Conflict with LLVM library

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, llvm

I am struggling to understand why the code below generates a segmentation fault. Without the myMap["0"] = 53; the program will run just fine. It would seem that when I attempt to use std::map with std::string as the key the program will crash due to some conflict within the LLVM library. However, if the key type is of any other datatype other than string the program will execute fine.

My impression was that even if the llvm library used the std::map with a string key, that the since the mapped_type is different a non-conflicting map template would be generated. So how is this error possible?

```
#include <string>   
#include <iostream>  
#include <IR/Module.h>  
#include <IRReader/IRReader.h>  
#include <Support/SourceMgr.h>  
#include <IR/LLVMContext.h>  
#include <memory>  
#include <map>  

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::unique_ptr;

using llvm::Module;
using llvm::LLVMContext;
using llvm::SMDiagnostic;


std::map<std::string, int> myMap;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    myMap["0"] = 53; // With this line included the program will seg fault

    string sFilePath = "varChange.ll";
    LLVMContext &Context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
    SMDiagnostic Err;
    unique_ptr<Module> module = parseIRFile(sFilePath.c_str(), Err, Context);
    cout << "Happily Exited" << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Here is the valgrind output of the seg fault:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)   
__memcmp_sse4_1 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)   
std::string::compare(std::string const&) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)   
bool std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:2571)    
std::less<std::string>::operator()(std::string const&, std::string const&) const (stl_function.h:235)      
std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >*, std::string const&) (stl_tree.h:1141)    
std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::lower_bound(std::string const&) (stl_tree.h:879)      
std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::lower_bound(std::string const&) (stl_map.h:864)    
std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::operator[](std::string&&) (stl_map.h:481)    
llvm::AttrBuilder::addAttribute(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef) (Attributes.cpp:1055)
llvm::LLParser::ParseFnAttributeValuePairs(llvm::AttrBuilder&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, bool, llvm::SMLoc&) (LLParser.cpp:939)    
llvm::LLParser::ParseUnnamedAttrGrp() (LLParser.cpp:882)    
llvm::LLParser::ParseTopLevelEntities() (LLParser.cpp:245)
```

Comment: Why does this `std::map<std::string, int> myMap;` need to be a global variable?

Comment: If you just have the code for the map in main do you still segfault?

Comment: It doesnt need to be global, this is just an example snippet I created after I figured out the conflict in a bigger piece of code. Before the map was a data member within a class.    
If I remove the parseIRFile line instead of the myMap["0"] = 53; the program will execute correctly.

Comment: I suspect there's another memory bug lurking in your code but without that line, it just happens to trash memory that's never used. Did you try running valgrind without that line?

Comment: @LPierce Divide and conquer.  Remove all code except for the standard #include headers.  Remove all code from `main` except for the map declaration.  Does the code now run?  If so, slowly add code until the problem appears.

Comment: @LPierce _"If I remove the `parseIRFile` line "_ So that's more likely to be source of your error. Also, do you have some static instantiation code that runs before `main()`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is the smallest working code example I could make. The issue is that parseIRFile resides in the Clang-LLVM library, along with LLVMContext and SMDiagnostic.    
Also, I have ran valgrind without the myMap["0"] = 53; and it runs free of errors, and the parsed content will appear correctly.

Comment: Based on the valgrind dump, it seems that it has something to do with the llvm::parseIRFile also using a std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, but why that would conflict with my own instantiation of the map class is beyond my understanding.

Comment: The valgrind output clearly puts the error somewhere inside the llvm library and has nothing to do with the `std::map<string,int>`. You could test if something is trashing the memory, replace the `std::map<..> myMap;` with `char myMap[128] = "hello world"`, replace the `myMap["0"]=53;` which `cout << myMap << endl;`. Then print it again at the end of `main()`, just before returning.

Comment: @haavee I agree the issue does seem to reside in the library. The peculiar thing is the following, in my larger program I do lots of processing on the module structure that is produced from this function with no issues and a clean valgrind, until I declared a map<string,  > in a completely unrelated part of the program.

Comment: The snippet above segfaults? Or is this an excerpt of the code that segfaulted?

Comment: @haavee the program above is a full program which seg faults.

Comment: There is also another valgrind error which seems to be from the main thread which points to 
std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::operator[](std::string&&) (stl_map.h:483)

As a the point of failure tracing all the way back from the parseIRFile line, which is the same operator as the myMap["0"] = 53; uses.

Answer (score 0):

I recompiled my llvm-clang library using the most recent version in the svn repo and the problem appears to be resolved.